# what will be the port number in the ip+port combination?

Tags: networking

```
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls reports
227 Entering Passive Mode (153,18,17,11,238,169)
150 Here comes the directory listing.
Entering Passive Mode (153,18,17,11,238,169)
```

the port number here decoded comes out to be 61097. its huge!! is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the last two digits are the port number, so 238 in hex is EE, and 169 in hex is A9.

EEA9 = 61097 decimal

[IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) allows for port numbers up to 65535